# How to perform an add functionality in sql loader file

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a fixed length data file a.dat with below data in it

> 1234544550002200011000330006600000

my focus is on specific positions

> POSITION(1:4)
>   POSITION(5:8)

and I want to add values in these 2 positions and insert it in a field named Qty in XYZ_Table.

I am trying to the following in my CTL file. But it fails, and I don't know how to pursue it further.

```
LOAD DATA
 INFILE '$SOME_DATA/a.dat'
 APPEND
 PRESERVE BLANKS
 INTO TABLE XYZ_Table
(QTY   POSITION(1:4)+POSITION(5:8)  "to_number(:QTY)")
```

I need to achieve this addition functionality in SQL Loader only.

If the above methodology is not possible, it would be great if you can help me with a different approach.

P.S: What I am trying to achieve is just one part of the bigger CTL file.

Comment: Why do you have this question tagged for both [mysql] and [oracle]?

Comment: Hi Bob, I am new to this forum, taking time to learn the right tags..

Answer (score 2):

You need to identify the positions you want to add together but not load into their own columns as "BOUNDFILLER", which means don't load them but remember them for use in an expression later.  Then use like this:

```
LOAD DATA
infile test.dat 
append
preserve blanks
INTO TABLE X_test
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(val_1  BOUNDFILLER position(1:4)
,val_2  BOUNDFILLER position(5:8)
,qty    ":val_1 + :val_2"
)
```